# How to treat underscores like space?

Tags: cursor-motions

Is it possible for vim to treat underscores like spaces or hypens, so when I use the sequence `dw`, it doesn't delete whole sentence `some_long_text_with_underscores`, when the cursor is at the beginning?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

`dw` deletes a word, and what constitutes a word is defined by the [`iskeyword`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#%27iskeyword%27) setting. From [`:h word`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/motion.txt.html#word):

```
                                                        word
A word consists of a sequence of letters, digits and underscores, or a
sequence of other non-blank characters, separated with white space (spaces,
tabs, <EOL>).  This can be changed with the 'iskeyword' option.  An empty line
is also considered to be a word.
```

To remove `_` from `iskeyword`, do:

```
set iskeyword-=_
```

Comment: It turned out to be a double-edged sword, as vim started to treat long function names as separate words. For example, a python function called ,,download_and_print()" is going to have colored ,,and'' - as this is a language keyword. It's also impossible to navigate with */# between function calls. I know it wasn't the part of the question, but wanted to mention this.

Comment: @zmarszczony my function highlighting works fine, but `*`/`#` is gone.